# MDX Selecting date dimension consumes huge amount of memory

Tags: performance, date, ssas, mdx

A following query takes 1 or 2 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Premium], [Measures].[Revenue] } 
ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (
[Insured].[PK Insured].[PK Insured].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Insured].[Named Insured].[Named Insured].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Producer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Producer].[PK Producer].[PK Producer].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Coverage Category].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Company].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Company].[PK Company].[PK Company].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Market Ownership Group].[PK Market Ownership Group].[PK Market Ownership Group].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Agency Ownership Group].[PK Agency Ownership Group].[PK Agency Ownership Group].ALLMEMBERS
* [Company].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS
) }
ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Marketing Rep].[PK Non Broker].&[820676] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( [Expiration Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2013-08-27T00:00:00] : [Expiration Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2013-11-25T00:00:00] ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Policy].[Status].&[PIF], [Policy].[Status].&[BIF] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [CrumpCRC]))) 
WHERE ( [Policy].[Status].CurrentMember, [Marketing Rep].[PK Non Broker].&[820676] )
```

If I add a date dimension (`Expiration Date`) then query takes minutes to execute, sometimes it even return memory overload error. This one is a problem:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Premium], [Measures].[Revenue] } 
ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (
[Insured].[PK Insured].[PK Insured].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Insured].[Named Insured].[Named Insured].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Producer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Producer].[PK Producer].[PK Producer].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Coverage Category].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Company].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Company].[PK Company].[PK Company].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Market Ownership Group].[PK Market Ownership Group].[PK Market Ownership Group].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Agency Ownership Group].[PK Agency Ownership Group].[PK Agency Ownership Group].ALLMEMBERS
* [Company].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS
* [Expiration Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].ALLMEMBERS
) }
ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Marketing Rep].[PK Non Broker].&[820676] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( [Expiration Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2013-08-27T00:00:00] : [Expiration Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date].&[2013-11-25T00:00:00] ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Policy].[Status].&[PIF], [Policy].[Status].&[BIF] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [CrumpCRC]))) 
WHERE ( [Policy].[Status].CurrentMember, [Marketing Rep].[PK Non Broker].&[820676] )
```

I was monitoring memory behaviour in task manager: When first query runs then nothing special happens with memory, but when I run second one (with date dim included) then memory jumps from 2GB to 8GB. I also noticed that as I start removing columns (with date included) query starts executing faster and memory consumption also starts to fall off. I have a feeling that adding each new column multiplies a number of operations needed to execute the query.

Difference between date and other dims is that date is set as a hierarchy. I've also included a warning message that I see for Year/Month attribute on hover

[image][image]

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Are any many-to-many relationships involved, especially with regard to Expiration date? Do you have any leaf level calculations in the calculation script? Your query contains 10 or 11 hierarchies in the rows. Do you really need all of them in one query? You could also try to group the hierarchies by dimension, this may improve performance, i. e. move `[Company].[Type]` up directly below `[Company].[PK Company]`.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute type error message indicates that you do no have your date dimension set to type Time.  here's a link explaining dimension types: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175452.aspx.

I believe when a query is executed against a cube, it looks at all the possible combinations of members for each selected dimension to find the intersections, so removing dimensions would improve performance because there aren't as many possible tuples. If this large (wide) query is something you will need to run regularly, you may want to review your aggregations in the cube. SQLCat has a [great whitepaper on performance tuning](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2011/10/10/analysis-services-2008-r2-performance-guide.aspx) both for cube design and query design  It explains the engine and what happens when a query is executed.

SSAS performance tuning is not my strong suit, but I would recommend [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/documentation) for validating and optimizing aggregations as well as overall dimension design.